# When Winter Bash 2021 Start?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

When **Winter Bash 2021** will start. We are really excited to participate this great fun event.

I love the "hat options" available in this event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will start 2021-12-15 at 12:00 UTC.

https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/